# Ownership of btrfs partition via fstab

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fstab, btrfs

I have a new disk with one `btrfs` partition on it and want to mount it via `fstab`. The problem is, that all files are now owned by `root` but I want them to be owned by the user with ID 1000 (and group ID 1000).

With the `ntfs` partition on my old disk the entry looked like this:

```
UUID=AAAE86DAAE869E87 /media/disk ntfs auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,errors=remount-ro 0
```

My current `btrfs` entry looks like this:

```
UUID=eaadb7d0-4dba-46a7-85ac-0fbf81821840 /media/disk btrfs defaults 0 1
```

I can't set the `uid` and `gid` option on `btrfs`, because when I do it, I'll get an error while booting (the options `uid` and `gid` do not exist).

Is there an opportunity to set the ownership of all files to a specific user?

Regards,
Hauke

Comment: btrfs, and ext support owners per-file, so change the ownership of the files. `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 /media/disk`

Comment: This will be persistent (so after a reboot the ownership is by user id 1000)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're thinking that `uid` and `gid` options in `fstab` are a generic way to override ownership on a filesystem.  That's not really true.  The NTFS driver, specifically, supports those options because NTFS doesn't store (Linux-compatible) ownership information on disk, so the driver has to fake them.

Btrfs, on the other hand, natively supports Linux file ownership, so there's no need for the driver to fake it; the btrfs driver has no `uid` or `gid` options.  If you want to change who owns something on a btrfs filesystem, just use the `chown` command.

If you want the "entire filesystem" to be owned by a specific user, mount it and then `chown` the mountpoint directory.  That sets the owner of the filesystem's root directory, so the user can create files there.  (And the files created by that user will, of course, be owned by that user.)

Comment: "[...] NTFS doesn't store (Linux-compatible) ownership information on disk [...]"
This was the part I forgot about, thanks a lot :D